# How to use resize_ffs in netbsd

Tags: netbsd

I'm trying to use `resize_ffs` with NetBSD to increase the size of my partition. I have NetBSD running in a virtual machine, and have expanded the size of the disk, and now wish to grow the partition to match.

Here is the [man page](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-7.0/resize_ffs.8) for the tool.

I am trying to grow a 300 MB partition to 1 GB.

The tool's man page says that specifying a size is not mandatory, and that if it is not specified it will grow to use available space (ideal behaviour). However this results in an error saying newsize not known.

I have used various online tools to try and calculate the disk geometry, but no matter what I try when I pass a number to `-s`, I get the error "bad magic number".

I have been unable to find example of using this tool online.

What is the correct way to use `resize_ffs` to grow a partition to use available disk space?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with NetBSD, but it seems to me that `resize_ffs` is the tool for resizing the filesystem within the partition. You'll probably first have to use some disk partitioning tool to increase the size of the partition, and then `resize_ffs` to make the filesystem use the new capacity within the partition.

Comment: Ah, that of course makes sense! However, after expanding the partition with fdisk, I get exactly the same errors when trying to use the tool

Comment: `bad magic number` means it cannot find a superblock.  Can you still `fsck` the filesystem? Are you sure you didn't move the start of the partition?

Comment: I can still fsck fine, and as far I know I didn't move the start of the partition